# Maximizing the minimum outdegree of digraph without $m$ cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple digraph on $n$ vertices without a directed cycle of length $m$
(it may have directed cycles of length less than $m$. The cycles need not be simple).

> How large the minimum outdegree $\delta^+$ can be?

For odd $m$ and even $n$ it is possible  $\delta^+ = n/2 $.

$r$ diregular digraphs of girth $g$ can be on $ r (g - 1) + 1$ vertices,
but this doesn't use the fact that smaller cycles may exists.

The case $m=3$ is interesting too.

Looks like Caccetta-Häggkvist Conjecture implies $\delta^+ < \frac{m n}{2 m - 1}$ for all $m,n$.